# Problem with a specific php session class

Tags: php, session

I am currently writing a PHP site for myself. Now I am trying to secure my site. Therefor I am using session. I don't want to write one for myself so I searched and found a wonderful example.

```
<?php
class SessionManager
{
    static function sessionStart($name, $limit = 0, $path = '/', $domain = null, $secure = null)
    {
        // Set the cookie name
        session_name($name . '_Session');
        // Set SSL level
        $https = isset($secure) ? $secure : isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']);
        // Set session cookie options
        session_set_cookie_params($limit, $path, $domain, $https, true);
        session_start();
        // Make sure the session hasn't expired, and destroy it if it has
        if(self::validateSession())
        {
            // Check to see if the session is new or a hijacking attempt
            if(!self::preventHijacking())
            {
                // Reset session data and regenerate id
                $_SESSION = array();
                $_SESSION['IPaddress'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
                            ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $_SESSION['userAgent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                self::regenerateSession();
            // Give a 5% chance of the session id changing on any request
            }elseif(rand(1, 100) <= 5){
                self::regenerateSession();
            }
        }else{
            $_SESSION = array();
            session_destroy();
            session_start();
        }
    }
    /**
     * This function regenerates a new ID and invalidates the old session. This should be called whenever permission
     * levels for a user change.
     *
     */
    static function regenerateSession()
    {
        // If this session is obsolete it means there already is a new id
        if(isset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']) || $_SESSION['OBSOLETE'] == true)
            return;
        // Set current session to expire in 10 seconds
        $_SESSION['OBSOLETE'] = true;
        $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] = time() + 10;
        // Create new session without destroying the old one
        session_regenerate_id(false);
        // Grab current session ID and close both sessions to allow other scripts to use them
        $newSession = session_id();
        session_write_close();
        // Set session ID to the new one, and start it back up again
        session_id($newSession);
        session_start();
        // Now we unset the obsolete and expiration values for the session we want to keep
        unset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']);
        unset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']);
    }
    /**
     * This function is used to see if a session has expired or not.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    static protected function validateSession()
    {
        if( isset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']) && !isset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']) )
            return false;
        if(isset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']) && $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] < time())
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * This function checks to make sure a session exists and is coming from the proper host. On new visits and hacking
     * attempts this function will return false.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    static protected function preventHijacking()
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['IPaddress']) || !isset($_SESSION['userAgent']))
            return false;
        if( $_SESSION['userAgent'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
            && !( strpos($_SESSION['userAgent'], ÔTridentÕ) !== false
                && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ÔTridentÕ) !== false))
        {
            return false;
        }
        $sessionIpSegment = substr($_SESSION['IPaddress'], 0, 7);
        $remoteIpHeader = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
            ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $remoteIpSegment = substr($remoteIpHeader, 0, 7);
        if($_SESSION['IPaddress'] != $remoteIpHeader
            && !(in_array($sessionIpSegment, $this->aolProxies) && in_array($remoteIpSegment, $this->aolProxies)))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if( $_SESSION['userAgent'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

I am trying to call the function over:

```
include 'SessionSafe.php';
SessionManager::sessionStart('InstallationName');
```

i am testing the session with:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    header('Location: Login.php');
}
```

Before, I wrote a value in `$_SESSION['userid']`, but I have the problem that the session variable is empty...

Comment: where are you testing the session ... the same file you have the `include`, the same request?

Comment: Where do you set the `userid` session variable?

Comment: the userid is set in LoginCheck and iam testing the session in the header of each side where i stard the session as well https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f81c6c4f4f740c73775bc5f9b1c6dfee20191101211600/56bde3 look their please are the files

Answer (score -2):

```
//File1.php
include 'SessionSafe.php';
session_start();
SessionManager::sessionStart('InstallationName');


// file2.php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
header('Location: Login.php');
}
```

You still have to use session start at the top of each php file.

Comment: The `sessionStart()` function calls `session_start()`. Calling it at the top should be equivalent.

Comment: Your call comes before the class does its extra work to secure the session.

Comment: so i put at the top in the class session manager as well and set the cookie afterwards?

Comment: and another question i started it in the header every time :O